# Compare resultset column with a excel column and if the values match, write data to adjacent column

Tags: java, excel

I have java programe that fetch data ( two columns) from a sql database. And I have a excel file which has three columns. The second column of the excel file and the first column of the result set has be compared. If they match, I want to write the value of the dataset's second column to the 4th column of excel file. I have this code so far. Problem is,this only checks the first cell and not moving to next cells. Please help

```
   int row = 0;
   while(row < 50) {
       cell = sheet.getRow(row).getCell(1);
       String cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
       while (results.next()) {
           String name = results.getString("StationName");
           if(cellValue.equals(name)) {
               System.out.println(results.getString("StationName"));
               System.out.println("Strings matched and values written !!!! ");
               newCell = sheet.getRow(row).getCell(3);
               int Bal = results.getInt(2);
               newCell.setCellValue(Bal);
           } else {
               System.out.println(results.getString("StationName"));
               System.out.println("Strings not matched!!! ");
           }
       }
       row = row + 1;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The site wont let me comment So this is not the answer but is a hint.
ResultSets iterate row wise,you will have to use while loop so that each value in the row will be traversed 
Somewhat like this :

```
while(results.next())
    {
    String name=results.getString(<Name>)
    if(cellValue.equals(name)) {
        System.out.println(results.getString("StationName"));
        System.out.println("Strings matched and values written !!!! ");
        newCell = sheet.getRow(row).getCell(3);
        int Bal = results.getInt(2);
        newCell.setCellValue(Bal);
       }
  }
```

Comment: My code loops through resultset's "stationName" column (approximately 100 rows) and check if the B1 cell matches with resultset's column. The problem is when this done checking the B1, it won't moved and check the B2 cell.

Comment: A suggestion : what if you create blocks of loops for getting data from each column eg get Column 1 data in first while loop get 2nd Column in 2nd while loop and so on.. and if you want to perform operations on data create another function.